# Non-infinitesimal linear expansion of a differential operator $X$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory

Consider a differential equation of the form
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = X(f)
$$
where $X$ is a linear operator. Then, if I am not mistaken, the infinitesimal change of $f$ from time $t$ to $dt$ is given as:
$$
f(t+dt) = e^{dt X}f
$$
which can be expanded as
$$
f(t+dt) = (1+Xdt)f + \text{ higher order terms}.
$$
My **question** is how can I compute a similar expansion for **a non-infinitesimal but arbitrarily small change** $t \to t + \Delta t$ and whether it still holds that to first order
$$
f(t+\delta t) = (1+X \delta t)f + \text{ higher order terms}.
$$
If the equation above is not correct, what is the best way to linearly approximate $e^{\delta t X}$ acting on $f$?

Comment: Hint : the relationship $f( t + \delta t) = e^{\delta t\,X}f$ holds for $\delta t$ of any size.

Comment: Right, so in the limit $\delta t \to 1/ \infty  = dt$ it holds too.